# flask run before create_app

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to using Flask for Python to write a microservice, but it needs to perform a series of actions before the API is started.  I tried to call the code in the create_app() function of Flask but found that flask completes regardless of if the calls complete.

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    connToSessionServerMade = False
    while connToSessionServerMade == False:
        connToSessionServerMade = ConnectToSessionServer()
        import Gateway.ApiEndpoint.SessionController
        return app
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you

Comment: Can you give some more information around what happens when you run the code, compared to what you're expecting to happen/desired outcome?

Comment: flask runs up regardless of the while loop

Comment: Why do you return `app` if connection is not ready yet? Remove indent in the last line.